# Integration of rational of polynomials

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, partial-fractions, rational-functions

I want to evaluate the indefinite integral for:
$$
\int\frac{x^3+3x−2}{x^2-3x+2}dx,\quad \text{for } x>2
$$
I did long division and factoring, simplifying it to
$$
\int x+3\,dx + \int\frac{10x-8}{(x-1)(x-2)}dx
$$
The integral for the first part is easy: $\frac{x^2}{2}+3x+c$. It's the second part I'm having trouble with. I looked up the solution for that part and it says that the second part simplifies to:
$$
\frac{12}{x-2}-\frac{2}{x-1}
$$
which can easily be integrated as $12\ln(x-2)-2\ln(x-1)+c$, which can be added to the last partial answer for the complete answer. I can see that when you multiply the two fractions in the difference above by $x-2$ and $x-1$ respectively and combine them, you arrive at the more complicated expression above. My question is, what reasoning can I use to get from the fraction above to these two simpler fractions, and how can I identify this case in other problems?

Comment: Look up: partial fractions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the construction called *partial fractions* ([Wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition)). The idea is that you want to write
$$
\frac{10x-8}{(x-1)(x-2)} = \frac{A}{x-1} + \frac{B}{x-2}
$$
so you can bring the RHS to common denominator and compare the numerators, getting 2 equations in 2 unknowns.

Comment: I see. So then I get $A(x-2) + B(x-1) = 10x - 8$, and the two equations are one in x and one in constant terms. Can I do a similar thing when the degree of the denominator is 3 or more? For example, let's say the denominator was (x-1)(x-2)(x-3). Could I then set it up for 3 equations (in x^2, x, and constant terms) in 3 unknowns?

Comment: @Hash88 yes. It becomes tricky when denominator gets powers though, e.g. $(x-1)(x-2)^2$, but there is a method there as well.

Comment: @Hash88 see the Wiki link in the answer

Comment: Thanks @gt6989b!

Answer (score 2):

Write: $$\frac{10x-8}{(x-1)(x-2)}= {a\over x-1}+{b\over x-2}$$

then you have to find $a$ and $b$. That you do after clearing the denominators:

$$10x-8 = a(x-2)+b(x-1)$$ so you have to solve a system $10 =a+b$ and $-8=-2a-b$